# Ubuntu 14.04 Brother MFC-J825DW fails to print

Tags: 14.04, printing, brother

I have searched online via Google, YouTube and Brother website but I was unable to find a solution.

I have an Acer Aspire V3-571 laptop, dual booted with Windows 7 Home Premium and Ubuntu 14.04.

I have J825 set up wireless. Laptop is set up wireless. Both are on my home LAN, along with Brother-HL-2270DW via USB to Dell E510 with Windows 7 Professional. I have a Netgear router WGR614v10 with wired Ethernet connection to E510 and VOIP and ISP provider.

Query of Ubuntu shows correct printer destination, printer accepting jobs. LED on J825 indicates "Receiving Data" BUT FAILS TO PRINT.

```
$ lpstat -t
scheduler is running
system default destination: Brother-MFC-J825DW:dnssd://Brother%20MFC-J825DW._ipp._tcp.local/ 
Brother-MPC-J825DW accepting requests since Thju 08 May 2014 01:14:11 AM EDT
printer Brother-MFC-J825DW is idle.
enabled since Thu 08 May 2014 1:14:11 AM EDT
```

I am brand new to Linux & Ubuntu Please advise.

Comment: Sounds similar to my issue, where "Print Self-Test Page" works fine, but "Print Test Page" and any other jobs I sent to networked brother printer (model HL-6180DW) would show up in CUPS "completed jobs", but never actually printed.  Dumindu's solution of installing all the Brother packages fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try with installing Brother printer drivers :

```
sudo apt-get install brother-cups-wrapper-common brother-cups-wrapper-extra brother-cups-wrapper-laser brother-cups-wrapper-laser1 brother-cups-wrapper-mfc9420cn
```

Comment: Dear 123456 As mentioned in my query, the problem is with the Brother MFC-J825DW -- a multifunction device consisting of scanner, fax, and printer (an inkjet printer). Please advise whether the  solution you gave for a laser printer will work for my inkjet printer.

Comment: No laser printers need to install foomatic printer drivers . See [here](http://www.allfreeubuntu.tk/drivers/)