# Brother printer not printing

Tags: networking, printing, cups-lpd

My Lubuntu 15.04 OS in an HP Notebook can connect, detect and has the drivers for a Brother MFC-J625DW Inkjet Multi-function printer. The Printer is wireless and is connected to other non-Linux computers in the same network.

But when I try to make a test print, it shows that it is "Unable to locate printer".

I've also tried using the default `System Tools > Printers > "Add"` after the drivers have been install. Same result.

I found an old fix (which I can't find anymore) involving using the IP address, rather than the Device URI. However, although it can locate the printer, it no longer responds and remains "Idle" after the command.

I've tried a long string of drivers as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463074/ubuntu-14-04-brother-mfc-j825dw-fails-to-print), but decided to remove them after it had no effect on the printer.

```
sudo apt-get install brother-cups-wrapper-common brother-cups-wrapper-extra brother-cups-wrapper-laser brother-cups-wrapper-laser1 brother-cups-wrapper-mfc9420cn
```

Anything else I should try?

===================

I think this info would mean something

- `http://localhost:631` contains the printer, but behaves the same way (Either Idle, or Unable to Locate)
- Running the IP address of my printer sends me to a page containing its name and links to AirPrint and Google Cloud Print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brother's printers are best installed via their own drivers, repositories, and such (in my experience). I have an MFC-7630n printer, but I suspect that the procedure will be similar.

So you can go here to download all the drivers and install them (this should bring you to your model):
http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=it&lang=it&prod=mfcj625dw_all&os=128&flang=English

Then you should assign a static IP address to your printer via your router interface or DHCP server and make sure it can be reached from your computers.

Finally, you should add the printer to your system and configure it to use an lpd string pointing to the IP you assigned it before plus the model name.

Mine is configured like this. Change your settings accordingly:

- Connection: lpd://192.168.1.254/mfc7360n
- Driver: Current - Brother MFC7360N for CUPS

(See comments below for OP's solution, based on this)

Comment: I noticed the only different with my settings and yours is that you have your printer's model instead of the port. I'll try this when I'm at the office again. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I tried the `.../mfcj625dw`, `.../mfc-j625dw`, `.../MFCJ625DW`and many others. ("..." is `lpd://192.168.1.111`) Still nothing but IDLE. I cannot accept your answer. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Uhm. If it is Idle, then maybe we can assume that the communication works, but the driver does not speak the right language? Did you try re-installing them from their website?

Comment: I was reluctant at first, but I tried using your link. I'm pretty sure it's the exact same stuff, but it somehow works. However, Instead of the URI (option 8), I tried using the IP address (option 9). It's a different connection compared to yours so please edit your answer to reflect this: `socket://192.168.1.111`. Many thanks.

Comment: Great to know :D

Answer (score 1):

[geckopi's advice](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=66281#p873510) to use the HL1250 PPD from foomatic-db helped me to get a Brother printer connected via USB printing. (MFC-7360N in my case.) To use this driver, I chose `Brother MFC-9600 Foomatic/hl1250` in CUPS settings.

Answer (score 0):

There are drivers in the Ubuntu repository for Brother "CUPS" drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install brother-lpr-drivers-laser brother-cups-wrapper-laser
```

You'll see new drivers in the list with names like "Brother MFC-7820N for CUPS" in the choice list. The BCL and Foomatic drivers don't work very well with some Brother models, particularly (maybe only) from PDF or Postscript sources. The "for CUPS" drivers *do* work however. I've been doing this for over four years now without issue (except when I get a new machine and forget to install those drivers).

I'm on 18.04 now and the drivers are still there.